# List Data ContainsAll Exactly Data In Other List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

In my business case I need to pick **codes** of cola brands which has assigned **third party dealers**  with codes.

I need to crosscheck all the dealer codes currently in contract are correct and no outside code is entered. To do that I have master list of codes.

***See the sample data I have***

```
List<String> mixedOfLAndPCodes = ["L123", "P123", "P234", "", "P2345", ""];
List<String> masterPCodes = ["P123", "P234", "P2345", "P111", "P23456"];
String masterLCode = "L123";
```

How can I be sure that all `mixedOfLAndPCodes` are available in master code list with `java stream`?

Code I wrote is something like

```
boolean a = mixedOfLAndPCodes.stream().allMatch(it -> masterLCode.equals(it) || masterPCodes.contains(it));
```

Not able to figure out if that is enough to test my case or some improvements needed.

Comment: How do you want to handle empty Strings? Your current code will return false, due to the presence of 2 empty Strings in the mixedOfLAndPCodes list. Is that the desired outcome?

Comment: Having empty string is okay. It mean no cola assigned to it.

Comment: In that case, you might want to filter out empty Strings from your Stream. Otherwise allMatch will return false.

Comment: Don’t you see any issues with code?

Comment: there is an issue with List instantiation it will not work. you should use something like `List.of("L123", "P123", "P234", "", "P2345", "")`. beside that and the already mentioned handling of empty strings it should work.

Comment: Well fine. That was just sample data. Definitely not static.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `Predicate` when i want to give a functional prespective on why i'm writing a certain code.

We can for your case, create a Predicate for each of you need then combine them to give an overview. Here is an example :

```
   public static Predicate<String> isExistingPMaster(List<String> pCodes) {
        return pCodes::contains;
   }

    public static Predicate<String> isExistingLMaster(List<String> lCodes) {
        return lCodes::contains; 
     /*
      * here we manage a list of lCodes but it also could be 
      * a single string with an equals() as in your question.
      *
      */
    }

    public static Predicate<String> isExistingInMaster(List<String> pCodes, List<String> lCodes) {
        return isExistingPMaster(pCodes).or(isExistingLMaster(lCodes));
    }
```

When predicates are created we can use them directly in streams :

```
List<String> mixedOfLAndPCodes = Arrays.asList("L123", "P123", "P234", "", "P2345", "");
List<String> masterPCodes = Arrays.asList("P123", "P234", "P2345", "P111", "P23456");
List<String> masterLCode = Arrays.asList("L123", "L125");

mixedOfLAndPCodes.stream().filter(isExistingInMaster(masterPCodes, masterLCode));
```

It flows well and even non-developer reads at a certain level.

Comment: masterCode is single String :)

Comment: Yes i noticed that. But my proposition is on purpose. Wether, it is a string or another that, it usually a good thing to separate things a part